# Regexp to find public members in Java source files

Tags: regex, parsing

In a language built on top of Java (so I cannot use regular parsers) I want to parse several sourc code files an extract the following information:

- name and extends/implements part of public (inner) classes
- public method declarations

So for a given file

```
public class A extends B {

  private int foo
  public int getFoo() {
    ...
  }

  private class Inner1 {

  }

  public class Inner2 {

  }
}
```

I would like to get with a single or several Regexps:

```
public class A extends B
public int getFoo()
public class Inner2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me know if this isn't quite complex enough, but it will basically look for "public" followed by a space, then anything that isn't an opening curly brace:

```
public\s[^{]+
```

Output is below:

[image]

Comment: Very good and easy, Simon! How / can I use regexp groups to extract from a match certain parts like the modifier, class name, extends/implments keyword and the secondary class. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: As my initial question was not so specific and Simon answered it perfectly I created a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14870742/regexp-to-match-members-declaration-of-java-source-files

Answer (score 0):

You'll want lines that start with any amount of whitespace, followed by `public`, followed by some whitespace, followed by a word character:

`^\s*public\s+\w`