# Regexp to match members declaration of Java source files

Tags: regex, parsing, apex-code

In a Javalike language where parsers and other advanced methods do not exist I want to parse and evaluate source files. It's the [language Apex from the proprietary cloud platform Salesforce.com](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index.htm). I know its based on Antrl/Java but there is no way to parse it from inside the platform as I want to parse Apex code with Apex code and the only means is Regexp.

When reading in a source file I want (by using a regexp) to match and extract all parts that are interesting to draw an UML class diagram:

- class declaration
- method declaration
- inner class declaration

I want to find them and by using Regexp groups I would love to be able to directly access parts of the matched string. Those parts are:

- Is is public or private?
- Is it static, abstract or default?
- Is it a class or an interface?
- What's the methodname?
- What's the Returntype?
- What's the param list?

Comment: What have you researched before asking? You said `Javalike language` - how is it similar or different from normal Java?

Comment: It's the language Apex from the proprietary cloud platform Salesforce.com. I know its based on Antrl/Java but there is no way to parse it from inside the platform as I want to parse Apex code with Apex code and the only means is Regexp.

Comment: Can you edit your question to state specifically it is Apex language? The documentation only show how to use it, but doesn't show much on the syntax of the language, so it is a bit troublesome to build a parser for it. I doubt regex can do the job, since you need to take care of nesting brackets.

Comment: I edited it as proposed. Could you please take back you downvote then?

Comment: To whoever visit this question later: http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Documentation . And the one that looks useful among the docs: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index.htm

Comment: I'd suggest Javacc but a google search only shows a non answered link http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Apex-Code-Development/javacc-rule-engine-for-Apex/td-p/186702